# Python and Selenium with PhantomJS gives empty page

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, phantomjs, socks

I'm using Python with Selenium and PhantomJS.

When I try to visit webpages with Socks4 or Socks5 proxy, I get an empty page.

```
phantomjs_path = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs'
service_args = [
    '--proxy=209.141.36.93:1080',
    '--proxy-type=socks4',
    '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
    '--ssl-protocol=any',
]
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920V Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36"
)

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,
                             service_args=service_args,
                             executable_path=phantomjs_path)

driver.get("http://2ip.ru")
time.sleep(10)
print driver.current_url
print driver.page_source
```

Result:

```
about:blank
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is related to the SSL encryption of the https sites so adding explicit waits isn't going to help.

From a previous post I noted that the following worked, call the PhantomJS driver as:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])
```